# Split text into selects

Tags: c#, regex

Having a string read from a file having next content:

```
select 1 from dual;
select 2 from dual;
select 3 from dual;
```

I wanted to extract each select statement using next regexp:

```
Regex.Split(sqlS, @";\s+\n")
```

The resulted array contains all selects, but the last one has the semi-colon at the end which is what I want to avoid. I would like to be able to split a text which contains many selects each of them ending with semi-colon. Each select start on a new line.

Comment: What about `File.ReadAllLines().Select(x => x.Trim(';'));`

Comment: Or, trimEnd the string before: `Regex.Split( sqlS.TrimEnd(new[] {';'}), @";\s*\n" )`.

Comment: Why not `string.Split` with `';'` as splitter?. Furthermore, if you are going to run the 3 queries as is, why not let the semicolon at the end of each, doesn't affect anything (IIRC).

Comment: If the selects are your "data" in a sense, I'd go for putting them in an XML or JSON, so you can simply have them deserialized into a datastructure (probably array or list). Without having to deal with their actual structure.

Comment: I can not change the format of the input strung so to say. but the idea for xml and json is a good one for a next version or refactoring of the application I wrote. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will try the solutions written for split. Best would be to not manipulate the string after split by remove last semi-colon but worse case need do that way.

Comment: You cannot remove and split at the same time without some additional output manipulation anyway. So, end-trimming the `;` before splitting might turn out a "more elegant" approach for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trim the `;` from the end of the string before splitting with your regex (I think `\s*` will work better, even if the line endings are not CRLF):

```cs
Regex.Split( sqlS.TrimEnd(new[] {';'}), @";\s*\n" )
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/aeNB3e):

```cs
var text = @"select 1 from dual;
select 2 from dual;
select 3 from dual;";
var output = Regex.Split( text.TrimEnd(new[] {';'}), @";\s*\n" );
foreach (var s in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Output:

```
select 1 from dual
select 2 from dual
select 3 from dual
```

Comment: I was thinking what if an sql statement is very long and has inside a string delimited by apostrophes the semi-colon. I assume this solution fails.

Comment: @ZitaKemeny In general, any regex will fail if you want to actually parse SQL syntax. You need a dedicated SQL parser then.

Answer (score 1):

If all sql statements are in a single file separated by `;` with new line, then you can try below code to get array of sql statement,

```
var filePath = @"C:\Program Files\sqlstatements.txt";

var sqlStatements = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)  //Read file and store all lines in an array
        .Select(x => x.Trim(';'))  //Now iterate over each line and remove semi-colon.
        .ToList();  //Optional: Convert String[] to List<string>
```

Comment: This looks also good. Thanks